# How can I draw a blood pressure graph in ipad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, graph

I'm developing a Graph application for iPad device. I used core plot 1.0 library for it but using core plot how can I draw this kind of chart? Can I use other library rather than core plot? Which library is better for drawing graphs like this? I was try to create MultiLine Graph and that works fine but I want to develop a graph like this.
[image: A Graph image]

A graph which I was develop like this.[image: Developed Graph by me]

Comment: You can always use other libraries... and with coreplot even you can... you need many customizations. You can use coreplot line chart and make some customizations and these kind of graph can be created, but you need to show some thing,. we can not provide you all the code, we can modify your work to resolve issue.

Comment: @V.V ok. but in image Twave is continues between two heart bit but using line graph i have a static line so how can i develop like this ?

Comment: you might be getting some data from the web services, so this thing is going to be finite for you, so over that point you may can get the start and the end point. there on you can draw a line with the points in the array.

Comment: Use [Core-Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of charting libraries on GitHub. I think one of them is called XYChart or something. They can generate these type of line graphs